# Has anyone successfully configured perforce clientspec for sonar scm plugin

Tags: perforce, sonarqube

I followed the instructions at this location.
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin

I have added this property to the sonar-project.properties file
sonar.scm.perforce.clientspec.name=ourClientName

when I ran the scan sonar interpreted the clientspec to be a contatenation of the clientspec and the hostname and the path of the file.
client spec name is: ourClientName
sonar host is in domain dev.company.com
The complete path to the file is: /data/home/auser/depot/CoreLibs/Dev-2013q4/src/test/com/company/base/csvparser/CSVPrinterTestCase.java

17:02:50.023 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: /data/home/auser/depot/CoreLibs/Dev-2013q4/src/test/com/company/base/csvparser/CSVPrinterTestCase.java. Reason: The perforce command failed.
CSVPrinterTestCase.java - must create client 'ourClientName.dev.company.com-MavenSCM--data-home-auser-depot-CoreLibs-Dev-2013q4-src-test-com-company-base-csvparser' to access local files.

(there is some obfuscation in the info)

Answer (score 2):

This property is available in version 1.6 (not yet released). I reverted the documentation to the proper workaround: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin